# Rmarkdown, plot title font as latin modern

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an `rmarkdown` document with single plot. I want to use the original fonts of `R` in the plot except the axis labels which should come from latin modern. I can use latin modern for all the fonts in the plot by `tikzDevice` package of `R`. But compiling this takes too much time when the data set used for plotting is very big.

OR, Can I use `tikzDevice` only for labels and title of the plot?

A summary code is below:

```
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(tikzDevice)
#opts_chunk$set(dev = 'tikz') # I don't want to use tikzDevice.
opts_chunk$set(dev.args=list(pointsize=12)) 
@

<<tikzfigure, echo = FALSE, fig.width = 4, fig.height = 4, fig.align = 'center', fig.pos = 'ht', tidy = TRUE>>=

plot(1:5,1:5,xlab=paste0("$\\sum \\beta_i$"))
@
```

The output:

[image]

The plot should stay as the same except the `x label` should be

[image]

(latin modern font.)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For the record, it was cross-posted at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550401/9128.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions for [mathematical annotation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) :

```
plot(1:5,1:5,xlab=expression(Sigma~beta[i]))
```

[image]